# Fail to concatenate two numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given two numpy array `a1` and `a2`:

```
>>>np.shape(a1)
(4465, 5000)
>>>np.shape(a2)
(4465, )
```

However,

```
>>>np.concatenate((a1, a2), axis=1)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have the same number of dimensions
```

And I also tried:

```
np.concatenate((a1, a2), axis=1),
np.concatenate((a1, a2.T), axis=0),
np.concatenate((a1, a2.T), axis=1)
```

But also got the same error.

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: What output are you expecting? An array of length 4465 by 5001?

Comment: @EdSmith Yes! That's what I want

Comment: @Alex Totally different. I didn't lost the parentheses. Just remove the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states, `a1` and `a2` do not have the same number of dimensions (accessible via attribute `ndims`). Make `a2` 2-dimensional with `a2 = a2[:, None]`. You can also use the more explicit syntax `a2 = a2[:, np.newaxis]`, but it is strictly equivalent.

Comment: `a2 = a2[:, np.newaxis]` works but `a2 = a2[:, None]` doesn't. Why??

Comment: Strange, which version of python/numpy as you using? You could also use `a2 = np.expand_dims(a2, 1)` or `a2 = np.atleast_2d(a2).T`

Comment: @ZICHAOLI try to avoid "doesn't work" on SO : do you get an error message or do you get unexpected results ? In both case, include them